# Looking for font inspector

Tags: gratis, font-utility

Like many Windows users, my computer has more fonts installed than is sensible. Since the Windows font folder/font display doesn’t allow any sort of grouping/sorting other than by font name, I need another utility to help me select fonts for use. Ideally, the utility must support the following:

1. Sorting/grouping by other than name. Specifically, I'd like to sort by the typical “class” of font, e.g., Serif, Sans-Serif, Monospace, Decorative/Script, Symbol/Dingbat - but a different/more granular set of classes doesn’t necessarily present a problem.
2. Display of a sample of the font. At a minimum, it should support an English pangram in lower case at a text size (e.g., 12pt or 14pt) and a display size (at least 24pt); ideally, I should be able to select the text (including non-Latin writing systems) and size.

Additional features that would be nice, but not essential:

3. Being able to group/sort by combination of classes, e.g., Monospace sans-serif. Grouping/sorting by Panose number would satisfy this.
4. Display of multiple attributes in the text sample, e.g., normal, bold, italic, underline, etc.
5. Being able to alter “header” data such as the font name and Panose number.